# Command doesn't respond

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

whenever I run this command the bot doesn't respond - no errors. I have the role that matched in r.id?

```
client.on('message', async message => {
    // Check if the user has a role with an id
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(!message.member.roles.cache.some(r => r.id === '1007043154182160466')){
        if (message.content === '.say') {
            const SayMessage = message.content.slice(4).trim();
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                message.delete()
             }, `50`)
            message.channel.send(SayMessage)
            client.channels.cache.get('100704202s2756065411').send(SayMessage + " " + "**from**" + " " + "**" + (message.author.username) + "**" + " " + "(" + (message.author) + ")")
          } else {
            return message.react('⛔');
          }
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a problem where you check the `message.content`. From your line with `message.content.slice(4).trim()` I assume the command you are creating requires more arguments, like ".say hello world" or something along those lines. So when you use `if (message.content === ".say")`, that checks if the content has *nothing* except ".say". There are a lot of ways to fix this, but for now you should just check if the content starts with .say, using the string.startsWith() function:

```
if (message.content.startsWith(".say")) {
    const SayMessage = message.content.slice(4).trim();
    // all the rest of your code here
}
```

Comment: I did those changes and it still doesn't work.

Comment: So I ran the code above on my server and it worked fine. A few things you need to check for: like @Zsolt mentioned, you never told us your discord.js version... if you're using v13 or 14 you need to use `client.on("messageCreate")` instead of just "message". And make sure you have the right gateway intents enabled when you create the client. Also make sure that's the correct role ID, and did you mean to have the exclamation point in front of `message.member.roles.cache.some`?

Comment: discordjs version 13.16.0

Comment: I guess the "message" event still exists in that version (although it's deprecated); have you enabled the right gateway intents?

Comment: Alright so, the bot now actually listens for the message but doesn't run the actual command. It just `return message.react('⛔');` and then nothing else happens, I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: You're using the code I posted, with the `startsWith()` function, right? Because if you were still using the code you originally posted, that would be exactly the error you get every time

Comment: I changed something and now it works, I think it was the gateway intents. Thank you!

Comment: Slight issue, now every message (except for !say) sent is now reacted with ⛔ please help it's havock

Comment: We should [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247192/discussion-between-rat-and-isaac-g)